# Facebook face detection and recognition

Tags: android, facebook, face-detection, face-recognition

Does facebook has API for face processing? Are there ways for using facebook face recognition and detection in your application? E.g. I have an application which uses facebook auth, so am I able to have all their face recognition and detection capabilities? Thanks

Comment: Why so much hate and downvote?

Comment: it´s not "hate" (that´s a pretty strong word), you just need to be more detailed with your question. for example, what have you tried so far? what did you research already? what exactly do you want to achieve? the more detailed your question is, the better the answers.

Comment: I was just asking for facebook capabilities and not others. If I would like to see any other suggestions I would ask to.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They do, but you can´t use their recognition in your own App. You would have to use an external recognition system like those:

- http://skybiometry.com/
- http://www.faceplusplus.com/
- http://blog.mashape.com/list-of-50-face-detection-recognition-apis/

The last link presents a large list of Face Recognition APIs.

Comment: I heared about those, currently I use skybiometry, but their detection capabilities are weaker.